# User-defined function with dplyr - mutate columns based on combining arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, nse

I am developing a shiny app using the following sample data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2014:2017, each = 10),
                 ID = rep(1:10, times = 4),
                 Score1 = runif(40),
                 Score2 = runif(40),
                 Score3 = runif(40)) %>% 
  gather(Score1, Score2, Score3, key = "Measure", value = "Value") %>% 
  unite(Measure, Year, col = "Measure", sep = "_") %>% 
  spread(Measure, Value)
```

Which gives:

```
> glimpse(df)
Observations: 10
Variables: 13
$ ID          <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
$ Score1_2014 <dbl> 0.03936843, 0.62027828, 0.56994489, 0.94410280, 0.98747476, 0.78021699, 0.5...
$ Score1_2015 <dbl> 0.456492381, 0.881373411, 0.601315132, 0.003073382, 0.436619197, 0.49193024...
$ Score1_2016 <dbl> 0.4937857, 0.4414206, 0.6716621, 0.2483740, 0.2376593, 0.4231311, 0.5250772...
$ Score1_2017 <dbl> 0.6824536, 0.1020127, 0.9973474, 0.4304465, 0.9194684, 0.8938086, 0.9133654...
$ Score2_2014 <dbl> 0.01550399, 0.03318784, 0.31463461, 0.99324685, 0.19417234, 0.10408623, 0.9...
$ Score2_2015 <dbl> 0.7631779, 0.4471922, 0.9119910, 0.5792838, 0.8458717, 0.9716529, 0.9580503...
$ Score2_2016 <dbl> 0.78565372, 0.20382477, 0.04103231, 0.33246223, 0.65301709, 0.03227641, 0.3...
$ Score2_2017 <dbl> 0.320235691, 0.211477745, 0.575208127, 0.290498894, 0.696220903, 0.94622610...
$ Score3_2014 <dbl> 0.93234031, 0.40570043, 0.07134056, 0.83916278, 0.57897129, 0.59457072, 0.3...
...
```

I would like to create a user-defined function that allows selecting the Score type (e.g. `Score1`, `Score2`, or `Score3`), a start year (`year_from`) and an end year (`year_to`), and calculates the difference between the years.  For instance, selecting `Score1`, `2015`, and `2016` would give:

```
   ID Score1_2016 Score1_2015        Diff
1   1   0.4937857 0.456492381  0.03729332
2   2   0.4414206 0.881373411 -0.43995279
3   3   0.6716621 0.601315132  0.07034700
4   4   0.2483740 0.003073382  0.24530064
5   5   0.2376593 0.436619197 -0.19895987
6   6   0.4231311 0.491930246 -0.06879918
7   7   0.5250772 0.596241541 -0.07116431
8   8   0.1416265 0.019224651  0.12240182
9   9   0.7573208 0.073456457  0.68386434
10 10   0.3575724 0.566328136 -0.20875574
```

---

I have read the documentation on [programming with `dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming), but not very confident in my use of `quosures`.  Attempting the following formula fails:

```
selectr <- function(data, value, year_from, year_to){
  recent <- max(year_from, year_to) # determine earlier year
  older <- min(year_from, year_to)
  recent.name <- paste(value, recent, sep = "_") # Create column names from original df
  older.name <- paste(value, older, sep = "_")
  recent.name <- enquo(recent.name) 
  older.name <- enquo(older.name)

  data %>% 
    select(ID, !!recent.name, !!older.name) %>% 
    mutate(Diff = !!recent.name - !!older.name)
}


selectr(data = df, 
        value = "Score1", 
        year_from = 2015, 
        year_to = 2016)
```

Which yields the error: `Error in !older.name : invalid argument type`

If I omit the `mutate(Diff = !!recent.name - !!older.name)`, the rest of the function works, but I really need the difference calculation within the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change two things for your function to work:

1. You want to convert recent.name and older.name from strings to symbols. This can be achieved with the `as.name()` function. The function `enquo()` converts a "promise" object to a quosure (symbol).
2. There seems to be a problem with operator precedence in the mutate step. If you change `!!` by `UQ()` (which is equivalent), the problem is solved.

This is a corrected version:

```
selectr <- function(data, value, year_from, year_to) {

  recent <- max(year_from, year_to) 
  older <- min(year_from, year_to)
  recent.name <- paste(value, recent, sep = "_") 
  older.name <- paste(value, older, sep = "_")
  recent.name <- as.name(recent.name) 
  older.name <- as.name(older.name)

  data %>% 
    select(ID, UQ(recent.name), UQ(older.name)) %>% 
    mutate(Diff = UQ(recent.name) - UQ(older.name))

}

selectr(data = df, 
        value = "Score1", 
        year_from = 2015, 
        year_to = 2016)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Any idea why `UQ()` works but `!!` doesn't?  The `id` argument was an artifact from me trying to make a more minimal, reproducible example.  I've edited the original question to remove it now.

Comment: I'm not really sure. Actually `!!` also works if you add extra parentheses, e.g. `Diff = (!!recent.name) - (!!older.name)`. My guess is that without the parentheses, one of the `!!`s is not recognized correctly and instead interpreted as two times `!`.